# How can a dialog become responsive while waiting for a call to DoModal() to return?

Tags: winapi, com, mfc, modal-dialog

A button on a dialog causes a child dialog to be created, and displayed modally.

e.g:

```
void ParentDialog::OnButton()
{
 ChildDialog dlg;
 int ret = dlg.DoModal();
}
```

The parent dialog is initially unresponsive as expected. But, the child dialog also makes COM calls to a server module, which causes the server to make COM calls back to the parent dialog... to update displayed data, etc. In one case, this causes the parent dialog to suddenly become responsive again even though the child dialog is still on screen. Both dialogs can now be interacted with even though the parent dialog is still patiently waiting for `OnButton()`to return.

How can this happen? I'm trawling the code but is there anything specific I should be looking for?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be Windows API code. Could you update the tags to include the framework in use?

Comment: Sorry, it's MFC. Added tag.

Comment: My crystal ball says that there is code somewhere, activated by the COM traffic, that calls EnableWindow().  Which is how that parent window could become interactive again.

Comment: @HansPassant are Modal dialogs really establishing their modality by nothing more complicated then disabling the parent window when shown, and enabling it when hidden?

Comment: Basically.  But they also pump a message loop which is why it blocks on OnButton().  MFC does it a bit different, can't remember the exact details.

Comment: I don't think COM messages enable or disable windows; it must be your code. I.e. can it be that you enable the dialog yourself in response to on one of those COM events you receive in the first dialog? I.e. the message loop runs so COM messages/calls are processed. BUT, it has nothing to do with enabling/disabling windows.

Comment: @Nikolay yes it seems this is the case, now I understand that Modal dialogs aren't doing anything special to _be_ modal, i.e. one can just enable the parent window and the dialog is no longer modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog has its own message pump/loop and inside the call it has a loop where it keeps receiving and dispatching window messages. This includes COM related messages worker windows receive and convert to COM callbacks you are seeing. Once the dialog is closed, respective windows are destroyed, the function exits from the loop and returns control to your code.

That is, without returning control to your code immediately, window message dispatching still keeps working as usually and UI is responsive.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452):

> ... The function displays the dialog box, disables the owner window, and starts its own message loop to retrieve and dispatch messages for the dialog box.
>
> When the dialog box procedure calls the EndDialog function, DialogBox destroys the dialog box, ends the message loop, enables the owner window (if previously enabled), and returns the nResult parameter specified by the dialog box procedure when it called EndDialog.

Comment: That makes sense, and seems to be suggesting (as Hans comments on the question) it's a perfectly normal API call not something 'magic'?

Comment: Yes, overall it is normal behavior and as it enables your window in an undesired way you perhaps want to set a break point in relevant place (such as WM_ENABLE handler) to find out what exactly on call stack at that time, and maybe there is some COM callback where you would want to check `IsWindowEnabled` and skip the event while owner window is disabled because of modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modeless dialog and use `RunModalLoop` to wait for the dialog to finish, somewhat similar to `DoModal()`

```
void CMyWnd::foo()
{
    static BOOL isOpen = FALSE;
    if (isOpen) return;//optional, prevents opening multiple dialogs

    CDialog dlg;
    dlg.Create(IDD_DIALOG1, this);
    dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    isOpen = TRUE;

    int result = dlg.RunModalLoop(0);
    dlg.DestroyWindow();
    isOpen = 0;

    TRACE("res:%d\n", result);
}
```

**Problem:** Note that in the above example you can close the program but the dialog will still be up. You have to force the dialog close, the above function doesn't deal with that.

Or you can create modeless dialog the usual way:

```
if (m_Dlg) return;
m_Dlg = new CDialog
m_Dlg.Create(IDD_DIALOG1, this);
m_Dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

However in this example if user clicks OK/Cancel then you don't know about it, you have to override `OnOK()/OnCancel` then send message to parent Window/Dialog, process message, and then destroy the dialog manually.